# function called inside form submit gets updated values on first click and never updates after that

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, blur

I'm trying to validate form elements on form submit, I have made a function for validation purpose which is working fine on elements blur event, when i use same function again inside form submit and trigger blur event for rechecking values in form elements, the function called inside submit works only on first click if there were no errors, but when I update values in fields, the submit function never updates.

Please help me out, here is my code

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="contact-form">
    <div class="form-gp">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-elem msg" placeholder="Type your message to the agent"></textarea>
    </div>
  <div class="form-gp">
    <input type="text" class="form-elem name" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-gp">
    <input type="text" class="form-elem phone" placeholder="Phone">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
var success = true;

function validator(){
        var $this = $(this),
            inpVal = $this.val();

    if (inpVal!=''){
        console.log(inpVal);
    } else {
            console.log('Empty value');
                success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

$('input[type="text"], textarea').on('blur', this, validator);


    $('.contact-form').submit('submit', function(){

    var elems = $(this).find('input[type="text"], textarea').blur(validator);
        elems.trigger('blur');

        if (success==true) {
                console.log('Form submitted successfully');
        } else {
                console.log("Form submission failure");
                return false;            
        } 
});
```

live code
https://jsfiddle.net/logiccanvas/cLygrhrr/1/

Comment: Should you use `$('.contact-form').on` instead of `$('.contact-form').submit`

Comment: Check the example [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit)

Comment: I'm using .on function, thanks for notification

Answer (score 1):

i have debugged your code, before every click the send button, you need to set `success = true` , add `success = true` code to your js file like this:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').on('blur', this, validator);


    $('.contact-form').submit('submit', function(){

    success = true;

    var elems = $(this).find('input[type="text"], textarea').blur(validator);
        elems.trigger('blur');

        if (success==true) {
                console.log('Form submitted successfully');
        } else {
                console.log("Form submission failure");
                return false;            
        } 
});
```

Comment: you are awesome. it really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. please remember to accept the answer if it helps u!

Answer (score 0):

i think triggering `blur` event inside `submit` is a bad idea. Did you notice how many console messages are showing each time clicking submit button ? here is an updated fiddle in my idea, try this

https://jsfiddle.net/26cyo83h/4/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, though your code works well on JSFiddle but for some reason $this variable doesn't work in my case. And I've fixed multiple console message issue on my local function. However, Thanks for your time.